# Designing an object in C++ that can be compared in multiple ways

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison

Suppose we have an object which represent a box.

```
class Box {
  public:
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;

    Box(int l, int w, int h);
    ~Box();
    int area(const int l, const int w) const;
    int volume(const int l, const int w, const int h) const; 
};
```

Now lets say in another class, in another file, we have an `std::list<Box>` that contains `n` boxes. We want to display a print out of these boxes in different ways.

- First we want to print them out in order of increasing size by their lengths.
- Then we want to print them out in order of increasing size by their widths.
- We don't care about their heights right now, but maybe later we will.

Now `std::list` has a member function `sort()` that takes a comparison function as an argument. How can we alter the above Box class so that we can call `sort()` on our list with different comparison functions?

More specifically, can we define three different functions inside the box class and simply pass them to `list.sort()`? Is it better to define the comparison functions globally outside of the class Intuitively, tying them to the class seems better but why would this not be the case? Overall, what is the "best" way to achieve this?

Comment: I think this explains one way to achieve that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/

Comment: It *might* be optimal to keep separate lists for each order especially if you will use them often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to implement the three different comparison
operations as members you can do something like this:

```
struct Box {
  int x, y, length;

  bool less_by_x(const Box& other) { return this.x < other.x; }
  bool less_by_y(const Box& other) { return this.y < other.y; }
  bool less_by_length(const Box& other) { return this.y < other.y; }
};
```

and use them like this:

```
#include <functional>
// you probably shouldn't be using a list anyway
std::list<Box> l; 
l.sort(std::mem_fun_ref(&Box::less_by_x));
```

`mem_fun_ref` returns an binary function object that takes a reference to the class of which the function is a member and all the rest of the arguments (only in C++11, this is limited to binary functions in C++03) of the member functions.

Although it seems much more reasonable to implement the comparison
operations as free functions.

Comment: I am using a list because before I get to this stage where I wish to display my boxes, I might be going through them and discarding any that are too big or too small.

Comment: I am not strict about implementing the comparisons operations as members rather than free functions. I thought it was better to include them as part of the class rather than global functions outside. If my thinking is incorrect and this suggestion is better I welcome to do it this way.

Comment: Implementation as members should be better as it preserves encapsulation.

Comment: @JoostSannen I fail to see how. What do you encapsulate better? If you make the `x`, `y` and `length` members private you will have to provide getters anyway and then can implement the comparison through those.

Comment: @mcorley I prefer everything that can be implemented as a free function should be implemented as such. Have a look at: http://drdobbs.com/184401197

Comment: @pmr This example does not have encapsulated data so we can only guess that users of Box need access to length, width and height. If they do, then a free function will obviously be able to use them. But if they don't then I would advise against providing getters just for the sake of comparing. (Of course you could make the free function a friend, but many coding standards do not allow this).

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a comparator function (or a function object). For example:

```
bool my_sort_function (const Box& box1, const Box& box2)
{
        // use some criteria and return a boolean (true if box1 goes before box2)
        // ...
}
```

Then invoke the `sort ()` method in the following way:

```
my_list.sort (my_sort_function);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass member functions as parameters then your best option is to use [boost::mem_fn](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html#Q1)

Answer (score 0):

`std::list::sort()` accepts a comparison function object, which lets you define custom sort criteria. This can be a normal function (free function or static member) or an instance of a class with a compatible `operator()`. See [some documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/) for details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

The various sorting functions in the standard C++ library take comparision objects. These may contain whatever data they need. The key requirements they have is that they are copyable and that their function call operator yields a strickt weak order when applied to objects of their argument type. It is easy to create a comparison object which e.g. stores a pointer to member function used to map an object to an attribute, especially if all the attributes have the same type (if the attributes have different types things are bit more interesting). With this it is rather straight forward to sort the same list into different orders.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement a comparison function for each parameter and pass that to sort when calling the sort.
That function boolean comparison(Box a, Box b) should be equivalent to a < b, that is, it is true if a comes before b when sorting by that parameter.